# project based ibuffer

Tags: projectile, ibuffer, persp-mode

I have emacs 27 on MacOS running in -nw mode.
I have prelude installed. It comes with projectile.

I regularly work on two git repos in my disk.

```
~/client1/
~/client2/
```

In any given day, I would open files in both those folders.
When I press C-x C-b, my list is littered with files from both
my clients, and it would be cool to see a "project based" view
of it.

The projectile GitHub readme says I can "switch between projects you have worked on". How?

That same readme also links to a plugin "https://github.com/bbatsov/persp-projectile", that also seems to do what I need. If that's a better option,
how do I use it?

FYI "C-x C-b runs the command ibuffer (found in global-map), which is an
interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in ‘ibuffer.el’."

Answer (score 1):

> In any given day, I would open files in both those folders. When I press C-x C-b, my list is littered with files from both my clients, and it would be cool to see a "project based" view of it.

Try `ibuffer-filter-by-projectile-files`. There are other `ibuffer-filter-by-*` you can use.

> The projectile GitHub readme says I can "switch between projects you have worked on". How?

Try `projectile-switch-project`

> That same readme also links to a plugin "https://github.com/bbatsov/persp-projectile", that also seems to do what I need. If that's a better option, how do I use it?

https://github.com/bbatsov/persp-projectile/blob/master/README.md
The README is pretty clear I think. You may walk through it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `projectile`, then probably [ibuffer-projectile](https://github.com/purcell/ibuffer-projectile) is what you're after.

From the README:

> `ibuffer-projectile` lets you group your buffers by their projectile
>   root directory.